# C wire not identified

Tags: wiring, thermostat, thermostat-c-wire

I have the c wire which I removed and reinserted but still the thermostat showing error that its not identified [image]

Comment: maybe the cable is damaged.

Comment: Are you sure you're using the correct C wire at the thermostat?  I see that you have 3 WHITE wires and two are connected to C.  It seems possible you connected W to C.

Comment: The white wires connected to c are returns wire with 2 power reds. Third white is part of 5 wires.

Comment: I have 2 wires with one connected w and c and other y and c besides the thermostat cable. I have checked my friends and he has same connections without any issue